# Why doesn't the GCC give any warning to these unused variables in the Linux kernel?

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

Normally, the compiler warns if a variable is declared but is never referenced.
In the Linux kernel source code, some unused functions and variables are marked  `__atrribute__((unused))`.

==> https://livegrep.com/search/linux?q=__attribute__((unused))

GCC, on the other hand, does not provide any warnings for these unused and unmarked variables like the integer `flags` in [kernel/sched/idle.c#427](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/sched/idle.c#L427) .

Why?

Comment: because the flags used in kernel compilation don't include `-Wunused-parameter` or `-Wextra` or similar which would warn about this.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved:

> Because we do not enable that build warning as it is mostly useless for
> kernel code due to how different apis work inside the kernel.
>
> Try enabling it yourself and see all of the noise that happens.
>
> ----
>
> greg k-h